# why collection.reset works like collection.add?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, signalr-hub, backbone.js-collections, backbone.signalr

I have a view with a Backbone collection. When I reset the collection through backbone.signalR hub, I expect to get a new collection which I pass through my hub but it just resets the collection and then works like calling `collection.add` on whatever was passed to it. So I get the 12 attributes in a model in my collection with first 6 null values and last 6 with current values.

My collection contains models with 6 attributes. I want to reset their values with the new 6 values. But I can not get through `collection.reset()`.

Before reset my collection I have a object contain following 6 attributes:

```
  customerId: 2, 
  expectedTimeOfService: "10 min",
  id: 6,
  noOfWaiting: 13, 
  queueName: "Cash Deposit",
  smsCode: "1234",
```

After reset my collection I get a object contain following 12 attributes:

```
  CustomerId: null,
  ExpectedTimeOfService: null,
  Id: null,
  NoOfWaiting: null,
  QueueName: null,
  SmsCode: null,
  customerId: 2,
  expectedTimeOfService: "10 min",
  id: 6,
  noOfWaiting: 13,
  queueName: "Cash Deposit",
  smsCode: "1234",
```

So, I can not get what's the problem or how can i get out from this problem. All I want to get my 6 attribute value with updated value after collection reset.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is case-sensitive, so `CustomerId` is not the same as `customerId`. When Backbone updates the model, it doesn't find a matching property, so it creates a new one.

You should fix the problem at the source and change the JSON keys returned by your service to `lowerCamelCase`.

If you can't for some reason change the service response, you could hack a conversion in `Model.parse`:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  parse: function (attrs) {
    var cleaned = {}
    _.each(attrs, function(val, key) {
      cleaned[key[0].toLowerCase() + key.slice(1)] = val;
    });
    return cleaned;
  }
});
```

And pass the option `parse:true` when reseting:

```
collection.reset(data, {parse:true});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @fencliff. Though it is a simple problem but sometimes it is very difficult to catch such simple problem. I have just solve my problem. Again thanks.